# Is there a way to OR several re.compile() outputs?

Tags: python, regex, boolean-logic

Suppose that I already have some objects created by `re.compile()`.

```
x = re.compile('abc')
y = re.compile('abd')
```

Is there a way to OR x and y into a new object?

```
z = re.compile('abc|abd')
```

Note that I used the original regexes "abc" and "abd". But in real situations, I may not know them, I only know `x` and `y`.

I would like to combine the orginal regexes into a new regex object. I don't want to use something like `any()` to check each regex, as the combined regex should work faster.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Can you maybe do `any()` on the iterable of outputs?

Comment: I don't want to use any(). I think that if multiple regexes can be merged into one, its performance may be better e.g., "abc|abd" should be faster than checking abc and then checking abd.

Comment: If you have e.g. "x" you can retrieve its flags and pattern with "x.flags" and "x.pattern" and use these to build a new regular expression.

Comment: @ggorlen As I mentioned, in reality, I may not know them. They may be created somewhere else.

Comment: Im not sure this is possible in the **general** case for arbitrary `x` and `y`.  One may have been compiled using *ignore case* for example, while the other has not.

Comment: Regular expressions can be combined with `|`, but the things that the `re` module works with aren't necessarily regular expressions.

Comment: Instead of `re.IGNORECASE`, use inline flag `(?i)`, then your regexes can be used together.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest would be to combine them string-wise with appropriate regex syntax:

```
x = re.compile('abc')
y = re.compile('abd')
z = re.compile('(?:%s)|(?:%s)' % (x.pattern, y.pattern))
```

You can do the same thing on a list too:

```
regexes = [
    re.compile('abc'),
    re.compile('abd')
]
z = re.compile('|'.join('(?:%s)' % i.pattern for i in regexes))
```

Note: This will **not** account for options to `re.compile` like `re.I` or `re.M`. You may want to include those as well, and throw an error if the options don't match.

```
def join_regexes(regexes):
    patterns = []
    for i, regex in enumerate(regexes):
        if not i:
            flags = regex.flags
        elif flags != regex.flags:
            raise Exception('regex flags need to match')
        patterns.append(regex.pattern)
    pattern = '|'.join('(?:%s)' % p for p in patterns)
    return re.compile(pattern, flags)
```

Comment: This assumes that the options of `re.compile()` are the same. What if there are things like ignore case that may be different among the original regexes?

Comment: @user1424739 That's a good point. I've added this case in the answer now.

Comment: So there is no way to deal with the case when the options don't match?

Comment: @user1424739 I'm afraid not. Python's `re` module applies all flags to the entire regex. Even the inline flags like `(?i)` are applied to the whole regex no matter where they are in the regex. The [PCRE regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) would give more flexibility in this regard, but would also require the inputs to be PCRE instead of Python regexes.